# Whats wrong with my recursive factorial example code in C#

Tags: c#

So I'm currently learning C# and I'm on Recursive Factorials, I followed instructions to create an example of the base case and the recursive case. But the program doesn't seem to be identifying my integer.

```
using System;

namespace Recursive_factorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Factorial(5);
        }
        public static int Factorial(int n)
        {
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return 1; //base case
            }
            else
            {
                return n * Factorial(n - 1); //recursive case
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to display the result, you're now ignoring it

Comment: Inside `Main`, you need `Console.WriteLine(Factorial(5));`

Comment: Welcome! As for "not identifying" your integer,  you aren't doing anything with the return value of `Factorial()`. I'd start there.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the problem is that you never show the result, try with

```
using System;

namespace Recursive_factorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Factorial(5));
        }
        public static int Factorial(int n)
        {
            if (n == 0)
                return 1;
            else
                return n * Factorial(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can add

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Below the Console.WriteLine, to pause the execution before it closes

Comment: If I input a negative number that will go on until you get a stack overflow (no pun intended) exception.

Comment: that's right, because that algoritm dont contemplate negative numbers, u can add them doing the inverse operation (+ instead of -) adding a condition that if n is less than 0... anyway im not sure that this techniche is for negative numbers

Comment: The algorithm may not, but the code does allow it, and it crashes. It's like you are not supposed to crash your car when you drive it, but in case you do, there is the airbag.

Comment: ohhh, sorry I didn't understand what you wanted to say, hahaha, well for that is more simple, u just have to add an if (n <0) and that return a message where says that you cant put negative numbers (sorry my eng)

Comment: the purpose of my comment was not to get an answer on how to do that, but for you to add to your answer so others, newbies, can copy and paste with real confidence.

Comment: Just FYI the question itself will likely be closed, as the issue is essentially caused by a typo/oversight. Typically these questions really don't need answers - a comment will usually suffice, pointing out the issue (which has been done at this point). I wouldn't worry too much about dealing with edge cases such as negative numbers - that's not even covered in the OP's original code, and is not related to the issue they were having.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice I'll keep it in mind, I couldn't comment before that I give the answer, had low reputation, im still defining what to answer and what not, just went to help :P, thanks again